# How do I see the server side dates in Dreamweaver CC?

Tags: server-side, dreamweaver

When I was using Dreamweaver CS6, I could always see the date and time on the server side when I uploaded a file to my website. I am now using Dreamweaver CC and the date and time are not visible. Therefore, when I upload a newer version of a page, I have no way of knowing for certain that the new file uploaded. I've tried to find the answer online, but I guess I am asking it incorrectly. If anyone can please tell me how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

I've tried to Google it but can't find the answer.